# SQL FileStream + Entity Framework store large files

Tags: entity-framework, filestream

When i want to store a file in a filestream column, i always need to read the whole binary into the memory:

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
   sourceStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
   binaryStore.Content = memoryStream.ToArray(); //Content = filestream column
}
```

is there a way with the entity framework, to put the stream directly? Because, if i want to upload a large file, i get a OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: Could this be resolved by using similar method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441179/outofmemoryexception-when-using-sql-filestream ? It seems to be using EntityFramework mixed with old type of connection.

Comment: yes, if is there not a another way, i will use this. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't see any update about FILESTREAM support in EF. (*Mentioned before as partial support with .net 3.5 sp1 release* [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/05/12/what-s-new-in-the-sp1-beta.aspx)). I suppose entity framework is accessing FILESTREAM through TSQL and apparent that you will not be able to get the streaming performance benefits of FILESTREAM. (*need to read all file content into memory*)

So, the recommended approach is using with `SqlFileStream` .Net API.

http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2011/08/22/using-sqlfilestream-in-c-to-access-sql-server-filestream-data/

Answer (score 8):

EF doesn't have any support for `FIlESTREAM`. It handles all interactions with `FILESTREAM` as normal `VARBINARY(MAX)` column so if you want to use streaming you must use ADO.NET directly.

Comment: Poking a 2 years old answer... Do you know if this is still true today?

Comment: Also have the same question. Is this still true?

Comment: @jpgrassi: I don't think there was any change because of how the real file stream works but I haven't use EF for quite some time, so I may be wrong.

Comment: This link can help, http://www.floatincode.net/post/sql-file-stream-in-asp.net-mvc-with-entity-framework

Answer (score 0):

You can do it however it requires some manual work. Requires `FILESTREAM` to be enabled.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/enable-and-configure-filestream

Table, notice the `unique rowguidcol not null` IdFile column that is required.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Files](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IdFile] [uniqueidentifier] unique ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [File] [varbinary](max) FILESTREAM  NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
))

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Files] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Files_IdFile]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [IdFile]
GO
```

EF model, IdFile column is not present, it only contains default values and is of no use for us. It is only used by SQL Server:

```
[Table("Files")]
public class FileModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public byte[] File { get; set; }
}
```

VM:

```
public class FileViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

Source:

http://www.floatincode.net/post/sql-file-stream-in-asp.net-mvc-with-entity-framework

Comment: Link is dead and setup info isnt in the answer