# CRUD operations by EF on sql table contains filestream column

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, filestream

I have a table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Files](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FileId] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [FileContent] [varbinary](max) FILESTREAM  NOT NULL,
    [Extinction] [nchar](5) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__Files] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] FILESTREAM_ON [FileStream],
 CONSTRAINT [UQ___Files__3214EC063158B01B] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [FileId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] FILESTREAM_ON [FileStream]
```

And map it into my model (Generated by EF 5). Now can I insert, or delete from this table using EF? Can anyone tell me how can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL FileStream + Entity Framework store large files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055280/sql-filestream-entity-framework-store-large-files)

Comment: Also see [this blog post on how to use EF with filestream](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2008/05/12/ado-net-entity-framework-support-filestream.aspx)