# How to define a new type of entity for my customer class?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework Code First in my system

Usually, I declare types int, string, double or other table class (other DbSet, I don't know what this called)

But now, I'm create a product system, content product photo, I want save the photo in the database too, I think can convert `BitmapImage` to `byte[]` for save a nvarchar[max] column

I don't know if this is possible...I want access Photo column and return a `BitmapImage`

```
public BitmapImage Photo { get; set; }
```

Is possible create a converter for `BitmapImage` entity? how to do it?

Sorry for my bad expression... I'm beginner in Entify Framework

Comment: Erm...why on EARTH would you want to convert it to a `Byte[]` then to `NVarChar(MAX)`? Please! [Look into using `System.IO.Stream` and storing them in the database as a FileStream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055280/sql-filestream-entity-framework-store-large-files). No it isn't possible. You can however stick a IValueConverter in your presentation layer, or better, in your View Model layer.

Comment: If you use the IMAGE control on a window or page it automatically converts a Byte[] to an Image. So you can store the image as a varbinary(MAX) in database (if using MSSQL) and simply bind it as a Byte[] all the way to Image control.

Comment: @Aron Sorry for my ignorance, I said it, because I don't know what can I do. So, I see this post, is very interesting! I will study about this, thank you so much! really really

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL field

```
fldImage    varbinary(MAX)  Checked
```

Model

```
 public Byte[] myImage
    {
        get { return myModel.myImage; }
        set
        {
            myModel.myImage = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Image");
        }
    }
```

Bind Byte[] to Image control on Window/Page

```
<Image x:Name="myImage"
       DataContext ="{Binding myDataContext}"
       Source="{Binding Path=myImage}"/>
```